# How to add differently shaped numpy arrays?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays.
One is a 2*2 array.

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

The other is a 2*2*4 array.

```
b = [[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]]
```

I want to add them so that I have a 2*2*4 array, c.

```
c = [[[1,0,0,0],[2,0,0,0]],[[3,0,0,0],[4,0,0,0]]]
```

What's the correct numpythonic way to do this?

Edit: This appears to work

```
  b[:,:,:1]+=a[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether you can do the sum in one single steps. Here it is in two steps:

```
c = b.copy()
c[...,0] += a
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my problem now. I was taking
`b[:,:,:1] to be the same as b[:,:,0]`